# C++ const char* to std::string &

Tags: c++, string, constants, std

I have a code that compiles, and it looks like:

```
    void test1(const std::string &name)................
    test1("myName");
```

But, if I remove the `const` from the declaration as:

```
    void test2(std::string &name)................
    test2("myName");
```

The code just doesn't compile.

Why the `const std::string` makes it compile? As far as I understand the same implicit constructor will be called for the `char *` to be converted to a `std::string`.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, in case this might be related to the answer.

Comment: Isn't the call `test1("myName");` too?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar yeah, sorry, I am adapting my code to be brief here and I missed this detail, thanks!

Comment: Another way to solve the compiler error is to make the function call in the second case as `test1(std::string("myName"));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the implicit conversion happens, you get a *temporary* `std::string` (technically, the important thing is that it is an xvalue).  You cannot bind a temporary to a lvalue reference `std::string &` but you can bind to a const lvalue reference `const std::string &` or an rvalue reference `std::string &&`.

The same thing happens here:

```
const int &x = 5;
int &x = 5; // error
```

Comment: I have heard about lvalue before...but not xvalue or rvalue...would you mind to elaborate more on the difference between them?

Comment: @mFeinstein: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Answer (score 2):

You get an error in second case because a temporary can not bind to a non-const reference.

`test("myName");` tries to bind temporary constructed object to a lvalue in second case, hence an error

Answer (score 2):

`"myName"` is a c-style string and it has the type of `const char[]`.  Since it is not a `std::string` it needs to be converted to one.  When that happens a temporary `string` is created.  That temporary string cannot be bound to a reference but it can be bound to a `const` reference as it will extend its lifetime to the end of the expression.

You could also pass the `string` by rvalue reference like `void foo(std::string && bar)`.  This will move the temporary `string` into the function and give you the same effect.

A third option is to pass the `string` by value `void foo(std::string bar)`.  This works with temporaries and non temporaries and will wither make a copy or a move depending on the source of the string.

Comment: Why the const will extend its lifetime?

Comment: @mfeinstein you should read this: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `&` you are using for reference. When calling the function with a **string literal** you cannot pass a non-const reference.